# problem with an urban airship sample app in android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

hi friends this is my first app in android urban airship, i just gone through this [link](http://urbanairship.com/docs/android-client-iap.html#)

i downloaded the sample app and i am trying to view the video which i want. When i run the app in my device the first activity opened and when i clicked the button in it showed a progress bar and said **"No products found"**.

But i have my video in  my urban airship account. I dont know where i am going wrong

Let me explain the steps i have followed

```
1. created an account in urban airship account and added a video in that account
2. i have added my apps package name and the Public key of my market.android account in than air ship site
3. in my app in the assets folder i have a file named as airshipconfig.properties.
   In that i have added the productionAppKey and productionAppSecret (i got those keys
   from my urban airship account)
4. in that file i have placed the inProduction = false
5. in the same file i had two more options as developmentAppkey and 
   developmentAppSecret. i dont know the keys for them so for developmentAppKey i
   have added the productionAppKey and for developmentSecretkey i have added the
   productionAppSecret.
```

i have posted my app in market.android.com, and i tried downloding the app from my device market but still i am not able to see any video's

please tell me where i am going wrong, please friends help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry friends, i commited a major mistake. In my urban airship account i a page named as supported platforms, in that i have selected only ios and not android. That's why i am able to view the video in my ios app alone.

now after selecting the android platform too i am able to download he video.